# How to avoid interpolation between sporadic metrics in Application Insights?

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have a job runner app that runs jobs sporadically throughout the day, and I'm reporting metrics for them. They don't run continuously, so AI interpolates between the gaps and the graph looks weird. I would like the graph to either not interpolate or just start/end at zero, so for now I am going to try reporting non-pre-aggregated zero values before and after the jobs, so at least this interpolation will be at the bottom of the graph and be easier to read.

Is there a correct way to indicate the end of a segment of values and the start of another, to avoid this?

Here is a good example of what I'm talking about:

[image: single series graph]

This is a single job runner from our staging env. which ran four jobs in this timeframe, and you can see where the dotted lines are between jobs. This is what I'm trying to avoid. This is exacerbated in a real environment with multiple runners or if you need to compare, e.g.:

[image: multi-series graph]

What I would like to do is somehow avoid the dotted lines and just go to/from zero (have all the dotted lines at the bottom so they don't interfere with other series). Maybe it's not possible.

I tried sending zero values (both direct and pre-aggregated) at the beginning and end of the jobs and using Operations hoping they would "bookend" the jobs, but neither seemed to do anything.

Comment: Josh, can you please paste a screenshot which illustrates a problem?

Comment: Thank you Josh! Reached out to product group which owns this experience.

Comment: Quick question - can you check whether scatter plot gives you better experience?

Comment: Ahh, wow, I never even noticed that drop-down in the UI before. That should work fine for us, or the bar chart. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Metrics Troubleshooting Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-troubleshoot#chart-shows-dashed-line) explains the dashes on the line chart type. Generally, the line chart is a great option for showing the *continuity* and *trends*. It is a poor option for showing *sparse* data points. It is so because this type of the chart is rendered by drawing the line segments between known values but *without* visualizing each value. For better illustration, think about how the line would look when there is only one known value on the entire chart. The two options could be: 1 - show a horizontal line (that’s what we do, but in addition, we add the dashed visualization so that you know the other values are missing) or 2 - not show the line and switch visualization to display just a dot (we let you do it manually by picking scattered plot chart option).